# using the enterprise library 5 to encrypt my connection strings and appSetting

Tags: .net, enterprise-library

I have a wpf4 that I am referenced the enterprise library 5. I want to encrypt my connectionstrings and appsettings but I am not 100% sure how to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for encrypting using the entlib5. There seems only to be useful information out there for the version 3.1 & 4.

Any help would be great!

Comment: All the Enterprise Libraries have been extensively documented on MSDN. Enterprise Library 5.0 - May 2011 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting parts of the configuration file is a feature of .NET and is transparent for any code reading the configuration file through the .NET configuration API.

You can read more about encrypting configuration files [here](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/11/17/2572.aspx) or use our good old [friend](http://www.google.nl/search?q=encrypting+connection+strings+in+.NET).

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer as the Enterprise Library 5.0 explicitly supports and concerns itself with encryption of configuration sections via the associated configuration tools.

Comment: Perhaps it was a different experience when the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 3):

To encrypt a configuration section using Enterprise Library 5:

> 1. Open one of the Enterprise Library configuration tools.
> 2. Open an existing configuration file or create a new one.
> 3. Click the chevron arrow at the right of name of the application block whose configuration information you want to encrypt.
> 4. In the Properties pane, click the drop-down list for the Protection Provider property.
> 5. Select either DataProtectionConfigurationProvider or RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider.

As per this url:

**Encrypting Configuration Data**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664594(v=pandp.50)

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the command line, not using the Enterprise Library configuration tools gui?  I am looking for a scriptable solution even if I have to write a small cli to do the work of the configuration tools.\

Answer (score 2):

The Enterprise Library Configuration Application Block Console.  You can open app.configs and web.configs with this and just select what encryption provider you want to use, and viola, your section is now encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on App.config and select "Edit Enterprise Library V5 Configuration". You will see two settings: Application Settings and Database Settings. Click the right arrow icon to toggle the general setting (very unfriendly UI :P). Click the drop-down list for Protection and then select RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider. Done :)

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt your configuration data with the EntLib config tool, follow [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664594%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx).